# Tapped Image inside a ListViewItem UWP C#

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, windows-10-universal, onitemclick

I have a listView that has an Image in every listViewItem. 
I have 2 events: ItemClick on the ListView and Tapped on the Image.
By default isItemClickEnabled is false in the listView, when it is false: the tap Image event works but not the ItemClick. When I set it to true: 
I tried setting e.OriginalSource in the ItemClick event, but it is always a ListView even when click on the Image: ItemClick works but not the tap Image event.

ItemClick event:

```
private void listView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.OriginalSource is Image)
                (e.OriginalSource as Image).Tapped += image_Tapped;
            else
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(nextPage), e.ClickedItem as Prayer);
        }
```

Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: e.OriginalSource will always be ListView, when you tap on image also.And image tap won't work when itemclick is enabled. Please explain the scenario do that I can help you

Comment: I just need to be able to click on the Image and fire the Image_Tapped event and when I click on any other element in the ListViewItem the ItemClick (or SelectionChanged) event of the ListView will be fired. 2 different events. Is that possible?

Comment: Why don't you have a tapped event handler in the image itself? You can get the datacontext of the tapped image if you require it.

Comment: @AbsoluteSith I am using the DataContext of the TappedImage inside the Image_Tapped event but this is not my problem. The ImageTapped event is not being fired when the ItemClick is enabled or SelectionChanged ListView event is set. I want both events to fire. One when I tap the image inside the ListViewItem and one when I tap anything else in the listViewItem.

Comment: How about you completely remove the listviews ItemClick and assuming you have a grid/stackpanel inside the DataTemplate then you could handle the tapped event handler for the grid/stackpanel. This might be an alternative solution

Comment: Or you can try button with content as image instead of image control

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trick to achieve this purpose. Place a Button on top of your Image to capture *Click* or *Tapped* event. First, You need to wrap your Image and Button in a Grid and then set Button's **Opacity** to **"0"** and its **VerticalAlignment** and **HorizontalAligment** to **"Stretch"**.

```
<Grid x:Name="ImageWrapper">
  <Image
    x:Name="Image" />
  <Button
    x:Name="ImageTapCaptureButton"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    Opacity="0"
    Tapped="Image_Tapped" />
</Grid>
```

**Note**: Button should be after Image in XAML because it needs to be on top of Image.

With this, you don't need to set **IsItemClickEnabled** to **"False"** and if you click anywhere out of your Image, it will trigger *ItemClick* event.